# Where to put custom SQL code in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm building an application in CakePHP 3. It uses a number of legacy databases which are not built in the Cake conventions.

I do not want to use any of the ORM features Cake provides, as it's more tedious to set up all the relations than just write "Raw SQL". We are also not going to make any changes to the database structures, so the ORM is a non-starter. So I'm going to write raw SQL queries for everything.

However, I'm not sure *where* this code would be put. I've read https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-select-statements but it doesn't say where you actually put that code.

I don't want to put my queries in a controller ideally since that defeats the purpose of MVC.

All I really need is one Model where I can put all my queries in different functions and reference them in my Controller(s).

In Cake 2.x it was easy to just create a model under `app/Model/` then load it (`loadModel`) where needed in controller(s). But with the new Cake 3.x `Table` and `Entity` spaces, I'm not sure how this fits in?

I've also read up on [Modelless Forms](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html) but don't think they're right either. For example the initial page of the application shows a list of chemicals which is just a `SELECT` statement - it doesn't involve forms or user input at all at this stage.

Obviously there will also be situations where I need to pass data from a Controller to the Model, e.g. queries based on user input.

Comment: Really? You want to ditch the power of the ORM and all related to it, just because of a bit of configuration work? Doesn't sound like a good trade to me, possibly the worst trade deal in the history of trade deals, maybe ever ;) That being said, you can always create any classes you like, anywhere you want, after all CakePHP is just PHP, the proper place for model related logic would naturally be the `Model` namespace.

Comment: @ndm, I agree totally with what you say. I don't want to do it the way I've planned but to give you an idea we have about 5 databases - none using Cake conventions. There are approx 20 tables in each one. Do you want to write the names of keys and relations for over 100 things? Or am I over-complicating it in my mind? We cannot change anything at the database level (as other applications have been coded). So it would all have to be defined in Models. Lots of database joins - is it easier to use the ORM or just write the SQL? It seems daunting to me :)

Comment: Incidentally, can you give an example of where to put the file (presumably in `src/Model`) and how to load it in the controller, if doing things the non-ORM way?

Comment: You overcomplicate it. It's really not that much work. In the 3h you're now waiting for an answer here you probably could have simply done all the assocs and table names. ;) I wouldn't ditch the ORM and go for SQL injections, sorry, pure SQL statements just because of that. Just learn the ORMs query builder, it might take time but it's worth the investment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I would suggest to not ditch the ORM, it has so many benefits, you'll most probably regret it in the long run.

Setting up the tables shouldn't be a big deal, you could bake everything, and do the refactoring with for example an IDE that does the dirty work of renaming references and filenames, and then set up the rules and associations manually, which might be a little tedious, but overally pretty simple, as there shouldn't really be much more to configure with respect to the database schema, than the foreign keys, and possibly the association property names (which might require updating possible entities `@property` annotations too) - maybe here and there also conditions and stuff, but oh well.

That being said, for the sake of completeness, you can always create any logic you want, anywhere you want. CakePHP is just PHP, so you could simply create a class somewhere in say the `Model` namespace (which is a natural fit for model related logic), and use it like any other class wherever needed.

```
// src/Model/SomeModelRelatedClass.php

namespace App\Model;

class SomeModelRelatedClass
{
    public function queryTheDatabase()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
$inst = new \App\Model\SomeModelRelatedClass();
$results = $inst->queryTheDatabase();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together > BelongsTo Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations)**